# Layout issues after migrating Bootstrap 3 to 4 (table width, elements inline not vertically stacked)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have migrated a simple ASP.NET site from Bootstrap 3.2.0 to 4.3.1 (using bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.bundle.min.js). Both before and after the site uses jQuery 3.2.1.

I converted the nav menu to fit with the new Bootstrap 4 design, wrapped the header and main content in Header and Main elements, and swapped all Glyphicon references to FontAwesome, but other than that the HTML remains the same.

I now have 2 major layout issues:

1. A table (used to display a grid of data) now has an automatic width of 407px, despite being told in CSS to be 100%. Under Bootstrap 3 it had an automatic width of 1140px (on a desktop display) while also being 100% in CSS. In other words, the table now "shrinks to fit" rather than expanding to fill available space.
2. There is an H1 heading and a button above the table. They now align horizontally rather then stack vertically.

I did read the documented [migration guidance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/), but I couldn't see anything there that told me why I get the above behaviour.

**Bootstrap 3:**
[image]

**Bootstrap 4:**
[image]

Comment: Follow the documented [migration guidance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/)

Comment: Yes, I have read that. However, I can't see anything there that tells me why I get the above behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue in the end ... and it was a little obscure. Hoping this helps someone else ....

As you can see from the above screenshot, in the Bootstrap 4 HTML, the content that has the problem is wrapped in a DIV with class="row justify-content-center".

The row class is from BS4, and sets *display: flex*

This has some unexpected effects on the child elements ... at least if you don't understand the new Flex display mode. For example, even though the child elements have *display: block*, they behave as if they have *display: inline*. So the H1 title and the button are inline not stacked, and also the DIV (after the H1) that contains the table shrinks to a minimum width (causing the table to shrink, as it is set to *width: 100%*).

The solution was to remove the row class from the DIV, so it was just class="justify-content-center".